# Bound state of $\mu^- \mu^+$ . Why non-relativistic muon states?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resonance, scattering-cross-section, helicity, mesons

Peskin & Schroeber page 148 discuss the creation of a $ \mu^+ \mu^-$ resonance state .

Equation (5.44) describes the creation of a **Spin Up** bound $ \mu^+ \mu^-$:
$$ \mathcal{M} = \sqrt{2M} \int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3} \tilde{\psi^*}(\vec{k}) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2m}}\mathcal{M}(\uparrow\uparrow\rightarrow\vec{k},-\vec{k})  $$

The amplitude is (5.39): 
$ \mathcal{M}(\uparrow\uparrow\rightarrow\vec{k},-\vec{k}) = -2e^2 $

My question is:
Is it necessary to use the non-relativistic amplitude?
Could we use the relativistic helicity amplitudes e.g. (5.32): $ \mathcal{M} = -e^2(1-\cos{\theta})  $ ?

I understand that the $\theta$ dependence makes the integration in (5.44) more complicated. But couldn't relativistic muon states form a resonance?
Thank you!

Comment: If the relative velocity of the two muons was anywhere near $c$ they'd have far too much energy to form a bound system. So using a non-relativistic expression seems an excellent approximation.

Comment: I agree.  $k_1$ and $k_2$ could be very large , "completely" relativistic. But what we care about though is  $ k = k_1 -k_2$ . This $k$ can be small if $k_1$ and $k_2$ are similar.

Comment: @Lefteris, those k's are vectors and they are opposite to each other in the C.M. frame.